# Animation is not playing while tool equiped

Tags: lua, roblox

I have problem:
Animation is not playing while tool is equiped, but when i click and unequip tool it's plays for a while.
I have no Errors in output

````
plr.CharacterAdded:Wait(1)
local animation = plr.Character:WaitForChild('Humanoid'):LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Animation)

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    print('event')
    animation:Play()
    script.Parent.Handle.Smash1:Play()
    wait(1)
    animation:Stop()
end)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
plr.CharacterAdded:Wait(1)
local animation = plr.Character:WaitForChild('Humanoid'):LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Animation)

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    print('event')
    animation.Priority = 2
    animation:Play()
    script.Parent.Handle.Smash1:Play()
    wait(1)
    animation:Stop()
end)
```

i found the problem, the Animation priority was the lowest so i have to change it to Highest by using `animation.Priority = 2`